# how to enhance tomcat thread pool behaviour

Tags: java, tomcat, threadpool

I'm running the java application using tomcat7.
I need to store the information per tomcat thread, so I can use the ThreadLocals approach.

In my server.xml the threadpool definition looks like the following:

```
 <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-" 
    maxThreads="10000" minSpareThreads="2000"/>
```

I have a class EnhanceThread

```
public class EnhanceThread extends Thread {
    ...
    @Override
    public void run() {
       SomeThreadLocals.set(data);
       super.run();
     }
}
```

How can I override the tomcat thread pool definition and make it use use my class? 
Is there a better approach to threat this problem?

Comment: Where does the data come from. If all the threads have the same data, what's the point? You should tell us more about your end goal. What do you put in the thread local?

Comment: I am sure everything is possible, but probably easier solution exists. Could you please explain what is the problem you want to solve?

Comment: I want to have a json serializer in thread locals of each thread in order to improve performance - not create it per each request, and not make it one centralized object

Comment: How have you identified that there is a performance problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to mess with Tomcat threads for that. Just use the following code:

```
public class JsonSerializerFactory {
    private static final ThreadLocal<JsonSerializer> JSON_SERIALIZER = 
        new ThreadLocal<JsonSerializer>() {
            @Override 
            protected JsonSerializer initialValue() {
                 return new JsonSerializer();
            }
        };

    public static JsonSerializer get() {
        return JSON_SERIALIZER;
    }
}
```

Each time you need a serializer, call `JsonSerializerFactory.get()`, and it will return the thread-local instance, and lazily create it if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Doesn't that create a memory leak if the application is redeployed? That is, when are these JsonSerializers removed?

Comment: Very nice answer, Thanks. About the redeploy - are the current threads become destroyed in redeploy?

Comment: It depends on the tomcat version. See http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection#customThreadLocal

Comment: An awesome example of why Tomcat had to add ThreadLocal leak protection.  This is not good code.

Comment: Just because Tomcat was unable to deal with such normal and straightforward code correctly in previous versions doesn't make it bad code. Application code should not have to deal with redeployment issues. That's the role of the app server. This is how ThreadLocal is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 0):

The Tomcat Executor is built on top of the java.util.concurrent classes, so you *could* replace the Tomcat component classes, but I don't think that's a good idea.

If you need to put data into the request scope, there are a number of well defined ways to do it in the Servlet Specification, for example the ServletRequestListener.  You could also use a Servlet Filter and selectively add it to only the requests that need it.