# tomcat thread local memory leak

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, thread-local

i'm using the thread locals approach to have a json serializer per each application thread to avoid the object creation each time i want to serialize it.

The code i'm using the following code:

```
public class JsonSerializerFactory {
    private static final ThreadLocal<JsonSerializer> JSON_SERIALIZER = 
        new ThreadLocal<JsonSerializer>() {
        @Override 
        protected JsonSerializer initialValue() {
             return new JsonSerializer();
        }
    };

public static JsonSerializer get() {
    return JSON_SERIALIZER;
}
```

}

each time i want to get the serializer i do:

```
JsonSerializerFactory.get()
```

When i'm shutting down the tomcat i see the following logs:

```
May 23, 2012 9:15:25 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader     clearReferencesThreads SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Logback AsyncAppender Dispatcher [Async_Logger] - Thread-16] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

I've read the [Tomcat memory leak protection](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection#customThreadLocal) but i probably missing something there.
Do I really have a leak, or should I ignore this message?

Could someone please explain?

see [how to enhance tomcat thread pool behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671503/how-to-enhance-tomcat-thread-pool-behaviour)

Comment: The tomcat log message refers to a logger (logback), not your JsonSerializer. The code you're quoting in this question is probably unrelated to your possible memory leak problem.

Comment: This logger has a json serializer in its thread locals

Comment: Logback AsyncAppender? You must be using a custom appender because as of today (2012-05-23) no AsyncAppender ships with logback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you use a `ThreadLocal` you should really have some way to clear it up. What tomcat is complaining about is that the thread created internally by logback has referenced this thread local and there for it won't be collected (assuming that thread doesn't die).

You can probably ignore this message if:

- Hot application reloads are not that important, its only a leak if you reload the app
- You know that the logback thread finishs when the application stops

What you might want to think about is whether or not you need a `ThreadLocal` cache in the first place. Is that `JsonSerializer` really that expensive? are you certain it isn't thread safe.

```
public class JsonSerializerFactory {
    public static JsonSerializer get() {
        // do this until you know you have a problem.
        return new JsonSerializer();
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm using actually Gson (1.7), and i saw that is has some syncronized method in construction. I need to check if version 2.2 is better performance

Comment: If it is performance issue, is there a good way to put it to thread locals, and somehow to enchance tomcat Thread and threadFactory?

Comment: From what I can see of the Gson API the main Gson object looks like it should be a singleton.. build once with your serialisiers/configuration and use it as a singleton. The latest manual says there is no state, so it should be thread safe

Comment: If i make it a bean i see the following code invoked from toJson method in ParameterizedTypeHandlerMap.getHandlerFor which is synchronized. This is bad for my runtime performance

Comment: I see your point, but I suspect that is a little bit of premature optimisation... uncontented synchronisation in java is silly fast. Put in on the list to worry about once you have profiled your app.

Comment: I have profiled it, and saw a lot of threads stacked there. But the good news is that as for gson 2.1 i can use it as a bean and the method toJson() doe not have a synchronized block. I just have to upgrade my package version.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say it has nothing to do with your code.